# odoo get the value of maximum array index

Tags: python, odoo

I got a function to append data into array :

```
def _get_state(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    idemployee = _default_employee(self, cr, uid, context=None)
    sql = " SELECT C.id AS id, C.sequence, C.name \
                   FROM wf_group_member A \
           LEFT JOIN wf_group B ON B.id = A.group_id \
           LEFT JOIN wf_process BB ON BB.id = B.process_id\
           LEFT JOIN wf_state C ON C.group_id = B.id \
           LEFT JOIN hr_employee D ON D.id = A.member_id \
           WHERE LOWER(code) = 'ca' AND member_id = %s ORDER BY sequence "
    res = []
    cr.execute(sql, [(idemployee)])
    ardata = cr.fetchall()
    for data in ardata:
        res.append((data[1], data[2]))
    return res
```

and then I tried to get the value of maximum array index :

```
def _get_maxstate(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    res = []
    arr_state = _get_state(self, cr, uid, context)
    states = len(arr_state) - 1
    res = arr_state[0][states]
    return res
```

But when I call _get_maxstate in action button, it raise error :

```
res = arr_state[0][states]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What's wrong with my code, help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`states` is an index to the last element of `arr_state`. However you do not index `arr_state` with `states`, you index it with `0` and then index the result with `states`. It seems like you probably want to just index the other way around, i.e. `arr_state[states][0]`.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, I miss that part, it solved by your answer